# pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 7 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

When running the below script it ends in the following error, as I do find other posts on this error I am not finding the fix similar to my script.

```
language = ['Chinese (Simplified)', 'Chinese (Traditional)', 'English', 'French', 'Indonesian', 'Japanese', 'Korean']

cursor.execute("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME WHERE Language=?", language)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

The Error I am getting :

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 1 parameter markers, but 7 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Comment: Make sense. You are sending multiple params into one placeholder qmark.

Comment: What is one placeholder and seven values *supposed* to do?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside language got 7 item but you only have 1 ? inside cursor.execute()
you can try 
lan=','.join([str(elem) for elem in language])

cursor.execute("SELECT * from TABLE_NAME WHERE Language in ?", lan)

Comment: - Thanks for the answer but still facing the same error.

Comment: ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in language]) 
this line make the list become string with , to separate each item